# mt_rand and rand not working (PHP)

Tags: php, random, php-7

I am having a problem where by when I try and generate numbers randomly with either mt_rand or rand (on a larger scale) I get no result at all. This used to work fine on my server but there seems to be issues now and I am unsure why.

```
<?php
echo 'Your number is: '.rand(0, 99999999999999999999);
?>
```

Where as it I update it to something like (using a 9 digit number):

```
<?php
echo 'Your number is: '.rand(0, 999999999);
?>
```

the lower example will work fine. I have recently changed my server version PHP 7.0. Is there a way to increase the maximum number or a better way to be doing this? Thanks.

Comment: You just need random string right ? whether it is numbers or characters ?

Comment: There is a constant called `PHP_INT_MAX`, maybe that is what you're looking for?

Comment: you are giving float value,thats why in php 7.0 it is giving you error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run the code in php 7 you have to typecast

```
<?php
echo 'Your number is: '.rand(0,(int) 99999999999999999999);
?>
```

Comment: Why? Do you mean in case strict_types=1 is enabled?

Comment: It is because `rand` expects the second parameter to be an integer. When a number is too big to fit in an integer PHP turns it into a float (which is able to contain bigger numbers). You should configure your server to show warnings when you are developing (PHP does [show a warning](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e565cbb80672a798489d28eac5d380f5e06bcc87));

Answer (score 2):

On both 32-bit and 64-bit systems, the number `99999999999999999999` is too large to be represented as an integer in PHP 7, so it becomes a float.

However, `mt_rand()` takes two integers. Because `99999999999999999999` is too large to be an integer, when you pass it to the function, [PHP 7 throws an error, because it cannot be safely converted](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/zpp_fail_on_overflow). You didn't get this error for `999999999`, because it's small enough to be an integer.

Anyway, your current code probably isn't doing that you want under PHP 5: `99999999999999999999` is being silently converted to `7766279631452241920` on 64-bit systems, and something else on 32-bit systems. So you're not getting the full range of random numbers. You wrote `rand(0, 99999999999999999999)`, but you're actually getting `rand(0, 7766279631452241920)`.

If you just want a random number from the widest possible range, try this:

```
<?php
echo 'Your number is: '.rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
?>
```

`PHP_INT_MAX` is a constant containing the largest possible integer (which will be different depending on whether you're on 32-bit or 64-bit). So, doing this will always give you the widest possible range of random positive numbers from that function.

Answer (score 0):

Microtime generated random everytime.

```
function microtimeRand( $min, $max ) {
    $microtimeInt = intval( microtime( true ) * 100 );
    $microtimeInt = $microtimeInt % ($max - $min);
    $microtimeInt += $min;

    return $microtimeInt;
}
```